# Boot Camp Control Panel macOS partition doesn't show up

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, high-sierra, dual-boot

Not sure why. I can access my macOS partition via hitting the option key. But the control panel doesn't seem to find it, And I want to set it as my default drive to boot into rather than Windows.

[image]

Below is the output from `diskutil list`.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [macOS partition disappered after installing windows 10 using bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp)

Comment: @DavidAnderson Without more information I'm not sure if this is a duplicate. I'm going to skip this for now.

Answer (score 2):

Since High Sierra, the macOS partition is formatted APFS. Due to what I presume is an oversight by Apple, the Boot Camp Control Panel only looks for HFS+ partitions as suitable startup disks. Therefore macOS partition won’t show in Boot Camp Control Panel since High Sierra.

To set macOS as default, use the Startup Disk preference pane in macOS System Preferences, or hold control as you select the disk from Startup Manager (the alt boot menu).

Comment: MURICA: Open  a Terminal application window and enter the command `diskutil list`. This command will not change your Mac. Post the output to your question. This will help confirm @JMY1000's concern about whether grgarside is correct.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/WcE2B

There ya go... @DavidAnderson

Answer (score 2):

What I found to be the best is a solution extracted from the [Apple discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8372939?page=1)... here from A-Z, without the noise...

What you need:

- The original Bootcamp installer package for your device
- brigadier https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier
- 7zip https://www.7-zip.org/

What you need to do:

1. Run the Bootcamp.msi installer in Drivers/Apple from your original Bootcamp pen drive / disk / folder
2. Choose the "Repair" option (it's the only option and will make sure that the AppleControlCenter is closed
3. Use brigadier to download the Bootcamp package for iMacPro1,1 (Open the command line with Run --> cmd (Enter) --> cd Downloads (Enter)(assuming you downloaded brigadier into Downloads))

   ```
   brigadier --model iMacPro1,1
   ```
4. Extract the Bootcamp.msi located in Drivers/Apple using 7zip (Right click, extract)
5. Go to C:\Windows\System32 and rename AppleControlPanel.exe to e.g. AppleControlPanel.orig.exe
6. Copy the AppleControlPanel.exe extracted from the iMacPro1,1 Bootcamp.msi package into c:\Windows\System32
7. Run AppleControlPanel.exe, verify that you see your macOS volume
8. Restart your computer, Apple Control Center should auto start and let you also successfully boot into macOS

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to the question: [macOS partition disappered after installing windows 10 using bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp). I posted an [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp/308654#308654) to this question. At this point, I can not recommend using this answer without first obtaining additional information about your Mac.

I will need the answers to the following questions and output from the commands given below. This information will determine if a fix is available. If a fix is possible, I could update this answer with instructions.

Questions:

- What version of Windows?
- What is the model/year of your Mac?

Unless you disable System Integrity Protection (SIP), the procedure given below requires booting to [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) via the internet, built-in recovery or an [USB flash drive macOS installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Once booted to [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), open a Terminal application window.

> Note: The Terminal application can be found under "Utilities" on the menu bar.

You need to post the output from the command given below. Edit your answer and paste in the output.

```
sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0
ls  -d  /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/Boot
```

Comment: I ended up fixing it by changing the target disk in macOS itself. I think the issue was what someone else mentioned of how due to the new APFS file system, maybe the devs of the bootcamp utility in windows didn't update the software to also look for APFS file systems.

Comment: I posted an answer to a problem similar to yours. See: [macOS partition disappered after installing windows 10 using bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp). This answer allowed the user to select macOS from Windows. The problem is I do not have enough information about your Mac to post, that my solution would have worked on you Mac. If interested in a fix for your Mac, I would need the additional information I requested.

Comment: @DavidAnderson hello David. can you help me with a similar problem?

Comment: @Nek: I can try. I assume you have already checked Apple Software Update while booted to Windows for any Boot Camp updates.

Comment: Thanks for answering! In the end the iCloud backup wasn't too old and I decided to just reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Windows, Search for:

> Apple Software Update

2. Click on it.
3. If any updates are available, click on Install.
4. Click Yes if prompted.
5. Then Restart.
6. If still cannot, check here - [No Mac Startup Disk - Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252622230?)

*Hope this helps!*

Answer (score 0):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418573/448770

Great! This solved it for me.

Macmini late 2014 and windows 10 pro

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/318078)