# Cannot access IMac OS (2009 X Snow Leopard) from Window 7 Bootcamp Control Panel or option key

Tags: windows, bootcamp, imac, partition, snow-leopard

I'm currently using an Imac 2009 running (Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.6) and I wish to switch from my  Windows 7 to my Mac OS and make that the default OS. Using the option key does not work. Bootcamp control panel can't find it either. It seems I'm unable to get back into Mac and this didn't seem to be an issues a year or ago?

[image]

It appears that my Mac HD still exists here, and I still have the install disk and often back up my files using time machine.

[image]

What would be the best solution for this, is there away to get back into my Mac or will I have to reinstall and back up from time machine (Unfortunately I know longer have the Windows 7 install disc) thank you in advanced.

NB I did look at the below link but wasn't sure if it was relevant to my issue as I'm essentially locked out of my Mac OS.
[Boot Camp Control Panel macOS partition doesn't show up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310109/boot-camp-control-panel-macos-partition-doesnt-show-up/418573)

Comment: Might be worth booting from the installation media, opening a Terminal window and entering the commands `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `fdisk /dev/disk0`. (You might have to prepend a `sudo` to the commands.) This would output the partition tables. There is a small chance the GPT (which OS X uses, but not Windows) has somehow become corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, would you recommend reinstalling the MacOS as Steve Chambers suggest. As a work around?

Comment: Hi David, unfortunately I wasn't even able to boot from the installation disc as my iMac ejected it 2mins after insertion. Any ideas why this could be (as it accepts other dvds and CDs) and would the next step be to take it to a specialist.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking reinstalling macOS will not remove or otherwise damage any user-generated files. This would include app settings (preferences) documents you have created, downloaded music/video, etc.

It is good that you have a backup, as you never really know why your system won't boot the installed macOS. In other words there may be some sort of file system damage that has corrupted both the OS and any other files.

I would go ahead and boot from the installer CD and select the current macOS partition as the target for installation and let it do its thing. Be sure you **do not reformat the Macintosh HD partition or anything else, just install!** It is *likely* that all your files will remain intact.

Comment: Thanks Steve will update on the outcome soon

Comment: Trying to boot from the original installer disc, but my iMac ejects the disc after 1/2 mins of processing? Unsure why this happens as the disc drive reads other disc CD and DVD. What is the next best option to take it to a specialist?

Comment: Sounds like a bad (and or damaged) install disc. I think there were more than one discs that came with Snow Leopard, you sure you have the right one?