# Keyboard not active in Bootcamp Manager

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, mac-pro, startup, apfs

*After moving to High Sierra, I realized that I can’t use the normal bootcamp preferences any more, since Windows won’t detect MacOS on the APFS volume. Apples workaround is to hold down the option key during startup to bring up the startup manager.*

I have an not officially supported graphics card in my MacPro, it needs a web driver, and I won’t **see** the startup manager since the web driver loads only after booting the operating system. I could choose the boot volume without seeing the startup manager, but strangely my USB-keyboard is not getting activated… which is strange, why can’t I use the keyboard, does this have anything to do with the graphics card?

So right now, the only way to change the operating system back from Windows to MacOS, is to physically install the old graphics card :-/

I’m disappointed that Apple didn’t warn Bootcamp-users about the whole APFS-compatibility-problem, and also that they don’t provide a fix for the bootcamp manager.

So the question again: is there another way to change the operating system without using the startup manager,
OR what can I do to persuade Mr. Startup-Manager to let me use the keyboard?

Comment: This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp/308654#308654) should solve your problem. You will have to make the appropriate substitutions. I could post an answer with the included substitutions, but I would need you to first post the output from `diskutil list`.