# Boot Camp Assistance is stuck on create a partition?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, high-sierra

I have a MacBook Pro, Late 2013. I have done a clean install of High Sierra macOS 10.13.3. I am trying to install Windows 10, Fall Creators Update, on my Mac by following Boot Camp Assistant's procedure.

My Boot Camp always halts after creating this partition window. It has been 6 hours and still it's showing this window. What is the solution to this?

[image]

Below is the output from `diskutil list`. This output is from after terminating the Boot Camp Assistant and restarting my Mac.

[image]

Here is a list of the files in the root folder of the flash drive.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the basic steps needed to install Windows 10 for an EFI boot.

> Note: To get a better view of the images shown below, either click on an image or open an image in a new window.

1. The command below will create the 70 GB "BOOTCAMP" partition on your internal drive. The space occupied by this partition will be used for installing Windows.

   ```
   sudo  diskutil  apfs  resizeContainer  disk0s2  180.8G  FAT32  BOOTCAMP  70G
   ```
2. Insert the flash drive containing the Windows 10 installation files and the Boot Camp Support Software. These files were already copied to the flash drive by the Boot Camp Assistant application.
3. Use the command shown below to rename the `AutoUnattend.xml` file.

   ```
   mv  /volumes/WINSTALL/AutoUnattend.xml  /volumes/WINSTALL/NoAutoUnattend.xml
   ```
4. Next, you need to boot from the volume where the Windows installation files reside. Hold down the option key immediately after restarting on your Mac. Release the option when the Startup Manager window appears. Select the icon labeled "EFI boot". Next, select the arrow below the "EFI boot" label.
5. Open a Windows Command Prompt window, by following the procedure outlined in this step. Below is an image of what is initially displayed by the Windows 10 installer. Select "Next".

   [image: z1]

   In the image shown below, select "Repair your computer".

   [image: z2]

   In the image shown below, select "Troubleshoot".

   [image: z3]

   In the image shown below, select "Command Prompt".

   [image: z4]

   The result should be the image shown below.

   [image: z6]
6. Use the command `diskpart` to finish partitioning `disk0`. The commands you need to enter are given below.

   > Note: Sometimes it can take a while for the `diskpart` command to produce the first prompt. Be patient.

   ```
   diskpart
   list  volume
   ```

   From the output of the command `list volume`, determine the number for the volume with the label "BOOTCAMP". In this example, I will assume the number is `0`. Your number could be different. The next command selects this partition.

   ```
   select  volume  0
   ```

   The next commands effect the "BOOTCAMP" volume. The format is changed to NTFS. Next, the size is shrunk by 600 MB.

   ```
   format  fs=ntfs  label=BOOTCAMP  quick
   shrink  desired=600
   ```

   Create a Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) partition. The next commands create and initialize an empty 600 MB WinRE.

   ```
   create  partition  primary
   set  id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
   gpt  attributes=0x8000000000000001
   format  fs=ntfs  label=Recovery  quick
   ```

   The next command lists the current volumes. Take note of the drive letter (Ltr) for the volume with label "WINSTALL". In this example, I will assume the letter is `D`. Your letter could be different.

   ```
   list  volume
   ```

   The command below quits the command `diskpart`.

   ```
   exit
   ```
7. Enter the command below to start the Windows installation. If the drive letter, for the "WINSTALL" volume, is not `D`, then make the appropriate substitute when entering the command below.

   ```
   setup  /unattend:D:\NoAutoUnattend.xml
   ```
8. When a window similar to what is shown below appears, select the "BOOTCAMP" partition, then click on the "Next" button.

   [image: d1]
9. Continue with the installation of Windows 10. If the computer boots back to macOS, goto System Preferences and select Windows as your startup disk. Restart the computer to continue initializing Windows 10.
10. When finished, the Windows Support Software installer should automatically launch. If this does **not** occur, use the Windows File Explorer to open the Windows Support Software application named "Setup". This application can be found in the "BootCamp" folder on the "WINSTALL" drive. After the installer application completes, allow the computer to restart.

If asked, I can clarify any of the above steps.

Comment: Thank you i have followed your guide exactly as guided and have sucessfully instaled windows 10, but i was wondering why i am not able to install windows by following apple offfical guide ? Why bootcamp is not able to perform partition ? Is it because my internel ssd is in APFS formt ?

Comment: The use of APFS is probably the reason. The other complaint, made by APFS users, is the lack of being able to boot back to macOS directly from Windows. For an example of this complaint and a possible solution, see [macOS partition disappered after installing windows 10 using bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp).

Comment: Thank you for making this! I know it's been like 4 months but this helped a lot. Thank youu so much