# Can't find AutoUnattend.xml?

Tags: bootcamp

I have followed this link https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316512/408833 in order to download Windows, and I have reached the part where I need to edit the AutoUnattend file, however I can't seem to find it on my USB. I've tried redownloading the support software and the iso file but still nothing (also tried the terminal command, says the file doesn't exist). Any help?

Answer (score 1):

*I have no idea the model/year of the OP's Mac, therefore this answer is based what I think would work.*

The Windows Support Software provided by Apple for the newer model Macs no longer includes an `AutoUnattend.xml` file. This file is not required to install Windows 10. With respect to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314111/boot-camp-assistance-is-stuck-on-create-a-partition/314177#314177), you can skip step 3 and replace step 7 with the step 7 given below.

7. Enter the command below to start the Windows installation.

   ```
   setup
   ```

When you finish installing Windows, you will have manually run the Windows Support Software installer, as explained in step 10.

> Note: The questions and answers linked to your question were created at a time when Apple was having the Boot Camp Assistant install Windows 10 with a separate recovery partition. The newer versions of the Boot Camp Assistant no longer do this, which significantly simplifies the installation procedure from what I previous posted.