# BootCamp not enough space problem

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, high-sierra

I am trying to install Windows using bootcamp in my Mac (High Sierra 10.13.4). However, bootcamp tells me that I do not have enough disk space while in fact I still have a lot. I am deleted all local snapshots.

```
vpn-global-dhcp2-151:~ mz$ sudo tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
vpn-global-dhcp2-151:~ mz$
```

I also tried `disktutils`:

```
vpn-global-dhcp2-151:~ mz$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MAC                     289.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
```

And `df -h`:

```
vpn-global-dhcp2-151:~ mz$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   466Gi  270Gi  192Gi    59% 2439867 9223372036852335940    0%   /
devfs          191Ki  191Ki    0Bi   100%     662                   0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4   466Gi  3.0Gi  192Gi     2%       3 9223372036854775804    0%   /private/var/vm
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0                   0  100%   /home
```

Also,`diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits`:

```
Resize limits for APFS Physical Store partition disk0s2:
  Current Physical Store partition size on map:   500.0 GB (499963170816 Bytes)
  Minimum (constrained by files/snapshots):       500.3 GB (500281479168 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum (if used with macOS):       500.0 GB (499963170816 Bytes)
  Maximum (constrained by partition map space):   500.0 GB (499963170816 Bytes)
```

And `diskutil apfs list`:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ mz$ diskutil apfs list
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 050EA8A3-B6E6-4950-AE74-CF7B63369E42
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      499963170816 B (500.0 GB)
    Minimum Size:                 500281479168 B (500.3 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   295298580480 B (295.3 GB) (59.1% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       204664590336 B (204.7 GB) (40.9% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 168DEE88-034B-42DF-B32C-0CCC7C4D14B3
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       499963170816 B (500.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 8C6AE51A-5316-4634-B8C6-6CB97AFF3447
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      MAC (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         291377287168 B (291.4 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 DF3F6FF3-7CF8-4712-BF36-3986E3C2AB27
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         22605824 B (22.6 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 2210A1EC-15A2-4013-8A93-89AB7CD59897
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         517758976 B (517.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 FA41CF69-ACF7-4343-9962-66A217CDCE27
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         3221245952 B (3.2 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Comment: What is the output from `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits` command? This command will not change your computer.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks. Added in the question description.

Comment: Your MAC volume appears to have a reserve of 5GB. I could confirm this, if you include the output from the command `diskutil apfs list`. This command will not change your computer. Having a reserve about the size of the drive would explain why the Boot Camp Assistant failed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Added. Seems I have unallocated space. Any ideas for this?