# Boot Camp Assistant stuck on creating partition due to EFI formatted as NTFS

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, ntfs, efi

Boot Camp Assistant is stuck on ‘create a partition’. I have followed the guide as answered in the question [Boot Camp Assistance is stuck on create a partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314111/boot-camp-assistance-is-stuck-on-create-a-partition/) but it didn't work after step 8. After I clicked on the "Next" button it says:

> Windows detected that the EFI system partition was formatted as NTFS. Format the EFI system partition as FAT32, and restart the installation.

What should I do?

Comment: You probably should have include the output from `diskutil list` in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try entering the following command in a macOS Terminal application window. This command should format the EFI system partition as FAT32.

```
sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -v EFI /dev/rdisk0s1
```

If the command fails, you could try entering the command while booted to [macOS Recovery over the Internet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314).

Answer (score 0):

when you get an option to select drive to  install,  delete all the drives you see , untill you only have 1 option ---->  " unallocated ".

Installation will go smoothly  after you do this

Comment: Won't that delete the macOS partition?