# Boot Camp Assistance is stuck on create a partition? Catalina 10.15.3

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, startup, catalina

I am having a similar issue to the following thread:

[Boot Camp Assistance is stuck on create a partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314111/boot-camp-assistance-is-stuck-on-create-a-partition/314177#314177?newreg=82831cfff8da48abbb3c63b7159b6154)

Except as shown below I'm stuck on 45% and there are some error messages I do not understand. Originally waited over 6 hours and then reached 45% in 30seconds.

Can anyone help? Thanks heaps in advance

[image: This is my computer details]