# is Windows not supporting NTFS Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, ntfs

So I couldn’t seem to partition my Late 2013 Mac with Bootcamp to run Windows 10.. it would just continue to show the partition part of the step for hours and hours. I became pretty sure it wouldn’t work. I decided to to search online and nothing seemed useful except this:

[Boot Camp Assistance is stuck on create a partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314111/boot-camp-assistance-is-stuck-on-create-a-partition)

Everything seemed to work perfectly. Until I got to the last step.. the partition is created. I’ve just clicked “Next” on the installation process and I gets pop-up saying this:

“Windows detected that the EFI system partition was formatted as NTFS. Format the EFI system partition as FAT32, and restart application.”

I thought NTFS was perfect for Windows 10. Should I try to change it to FAT32??? Should I try something else? A step by step guide would be nice..

I should probably include `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         180.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                68.7 GB    disk0s3
   4:           Windows Recovery                         629.1 MB   disk0s4
   5:           Windows Recovery                         629.1 MB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +180.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume \,L0\ - Data            132.2 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume \,L0\                   11.2 GB    disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.1 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS WinInstall              2.1 TB     disk2s1
```

Comment: It does. i followed the link stated above and the format was NTFS which makes sense. And besides, I've already tried formatting to FAT32. It didn't work... it gave an error then saying GTP partition isn't supported. At this point, I'm willing to start from scratch if there's anyone here willing to guide me through it.

Comment: I *think* the key here is that it is talking about the **EFI** partition not the partition on which Windows is installed. Check it out here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition