# Error while setting up windows in my late 2014 iMac

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows, partition, setup

[Boot Camp Assistance is stuck on create a partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314111/boot-camp-assistance-is-stuck-on-create-a-partition) So I used the procedures in this link to try and set up windows in my iMac , but when it reached the part where they asked where do you want install Windows and after I select BOOT CAMP, I got an error - " We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one."[image]

Comment: I don't have a way out of the pickle you find yourself in but you have two system & EFI partitions on your Mac, where you should have one each. You also have three primary partitions (where macOS and Windows would go) And you may be over the number of partitions possible for a working BootCamp installation, which would be the reason for the error. Other than deleting all of those partitions and starting over from scratch (assuming you have a backup of what is already there) I am unsure how to help you get out of this pickle.

Comment: @SteveChambers: There are two drives in the image. Each has a single System (EFI) partition. This is not unusual. There is a primary partition on each drive for possibly a macOS fusion arrangement. The primary partition labeled `BOOTCAMP` and recovery partition labeled `Recovery` are for Windows. I never understood why users post that they do not know the answer, but the solution should be to start over.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is you are trying to install to the second HDD or SSD. The link you gave is for installing to a Mac with a single internal HDD or SSD. The Windows installer GUI is not equipped to handle your situation. One possible alternative would be to use the CLI to install Windows.

> Note: I am using the Windows 10 20H2 English 64 bit version. In other words. the Windows 10 October 2020 update.

Starting from the window posted as an image in your question, proceed as follows.

1. Click on the red X to close the window. In the popup window, click on the `Yes` button.
2. Enter the following commands to start `diskpart` and get a list of volumes.

   ```
   diskpart
   list volume
   ```
3. Assign a drive letter `P` to the flash drive. In the first command given below, replace the `#` symbol with the volume number for the flash drive given in the previous step.

   ```
   select volume #
   assign letter=p
   ```
4. Assign drive letters to the EFI and Windows partitions.

   ```
   select disk 1
   setect partition 1
   assign letter=s
   select partition 3
   assign letter=w
   ```
5. Enter the following command to quit `diskpart`.

   ```
   exit
   ```
6. This command applies the Windows image to the desired partition.

   ```
   dism /apply-image /imagefile:p:\sources\install.wim /name:"Windows 10 Pro" /applydir:w:\ /checkintegrity
   ```

   Note: If you do not what `Windows 10 Pro` and do not know the desired name, then you can get a list of available names by entering the following command.

   ```
   dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:p:\sources\install.wim
   ```
7. This command copies the drivers provided by Apple to the drivers store.

   ```
   dism /image:w:\ /add-driver /driver:p:\$WinPEDriver$ /recurse /forceunsigned
   ```

   > Note: This step searches for `.inf` files. If a found `.inf` file does not result in a driver being properly copied to the driver store, then an error message may be generated. You can ignore such messages. For example, some drivers can only be installed after Windows has finished installing.
8. Create the boot files. The command below installs for US English.

   ```
   bcdboot w:\windows /l en-us /s s: /f uefi
   ```
9. Close the command prompt window and select to `Turn off your PC`. In other words, shutdown the Mac.

   ```
   exit
   ```
10. Start the Mac and continue with the installation of Windows. If you boot to macOS, then select Windows from the Startup Disk pane of the System Preferences application.
11. When finished installing Windows, install the Windows Support Software provided by Apple. Look for the `Setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder on the flash drive.
12. From Windows, run the Apple Software Update application to get any Boot Camp and other software updates from Apple.

### Updating AMD graphics drivers for Windows in Boot Camp

Apple has a website [Update AMD graphics drivers for Windows in Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208908) which provides a link to the [AMD website homepage](https://www.amd.com/en). Clicking on [Drivers and Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support) takes you to a webpage where there is a `Download Now` button which will download software to *"Auto-Detect and Install Radeon™ Graphics Drivers for Windows®"*. You can also select your product from the list. According to [everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/imac-aluminum-tapered-edge-faq/imac-aluminum-tapered-edge-display-vesa-details.html#video_processor) your late 2014 iMac has a Radeon R9 M290X dedicated video processor. Going though the list took me to the [AMD Radeon™ R9 M290X Drivers & Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-r9-series/amd-radeon-r9-200-series/amd-radeon-r9-m290x) webpage. For the *"Windows 10 - 64-Bit Edition"*, there is a download under the title *"Auto-Detect and Install"*. This download is the same as the one found on the [Drivers and Support](https://www.amd.com/en/support) webpage. There are also various versions of the drivers you could download and try.

Comment: I successfully installed windows 10 using those steps, but it terribly slow, don't judge me but, I tried running Rocket League on it and it seemed like it was running at 1 Hz refresh rate..

Comment: I updated my answer to include how to update the graphics driver. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: so I downloaded the driver and installed it but I got an error from that software "Error 173- Radeon Software install cannot proceed as no AMD graphics hardware has been detected in your system configuration". Is there a fix for this?