# How to remove a container disk and reclaim space with main partition?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, apfs

I used to have a bootcamp partition but somehow while attempting to remove it its changed into a container disk. (don't know how this happened, I didn't explicitly create a container).

[image]

[image]

diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         402.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         97.8 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +402.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            336.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                515.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +97.8 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
```

How can I delete this and merge its space back into the main drive?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here, I assume the macOS volume that you boot to is `Macintosh HD`.

The commands below should remove the extra partitions and return the free space back to macOS.

```
 diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4 
 diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk0s3 Untitled
 diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
 diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

If you are using Big Sur or newer, then you can just enter the commands given below.

```
 diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s4 
 diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk0s3
 diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a non-command line version, there is also a way to do it from the native *Disk Utility* app.

1. Open Disk Utility.
2. Select the partition in the lefthand menu.
3. Right click --> "Erase" (it will now rename to Container disk#)
4. In the top righthand menu, press "Partition"
5. Select the desired partition in the pie chart
6. Press the "-" (minus) option directly under the Pie chart
7. Wait for confirmation message (***APPLE SSD AP0512M Media has been cleaned***)