# Failed to remove container disk and reclaim space to main partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, apfs

After I removed Boot Camp I found out that the partition space didn't merge back into my main volume, instead it was called "container disk1". There was no option to delete it so I tried to initialize it and I renamed it "boh".
Following the answer that was given to this question: [How to remove a container disk and reclaim space with main partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347751/how-to-remove-a-container-disk-and-reclaim-space-with-main-partition), I ran `diskutil list` and obtained

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         200.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         50.7 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +50.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨boh⁩                     708.6 KB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +200.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.7 GB    disk2s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.7 GB    disk2s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 302.6 MB   disk2s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk2s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk2s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Dati⁩     115.9 GB   disk2s5
```

Then `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3` and it returned:

```
The target disk is in use by APFS as a Physical Store; use diskutil apfs deleteContainer
```

so I ran `diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s3` and now when I type `diskutil list`
this is what I see:

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         200.0 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         50.7 GB    -

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +200.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.7 GB    disk2s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.7 GB    disk2s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 302.6 MB   disk2s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk2s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk2s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Dati⁩     115.9 GB   disk2s5
```

And now I'm scared that I messed it up. The volume doesn't either show up in Disk Utility.

I have a 2016 MacBook Pro 13-inch 4 TBT3, running MacOS Monterey 12.0.1
Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347751/how-to-remove-a-container-disk-and-reclaim-space-with-main-partition/347760#347760) the OP (user [federico.jpg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/441927/federico-jpg)) was referring to has been updated. The version of the accepted answer that the OP read when posting the question can been seen [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/347760/1).

Since the question you referenced was posted, macOS has changed. You no longer have to enter the command below. This is the third command shown in the accepted answer.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

Instead, you just need to enter the command below, which is the final command shown in the accepted answer.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```