# How to boot into macOS directly in Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp

I just got Boot Camp with Windows 10 on my Mac. How can I boot into macOS without having to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> key after the chime sound?

Currently, when I start the Mac normally, it boots into Windows, and then I have to switch from there to Mac which requires another restart. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? Are you using APFS? What is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: I am on macOS 10.14.5. I have no idea what APFS is, I'm not really a techy guy. My iMac is from late 2015.

Comment: If Scott Earle's answer does not work, then you can try my answer posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308361/macos-partition-disappered-after-installing-windows-10-using-bootcamp/308654#308654). Unfortunately, my answer is rather complicated to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Boot Camp Control Panel in Windows, you can select the boot drive in there. This will be in effect until you change it again from within macOS's Startup Disk system preference.